# Eisenstein series and large-$n$ behavior

Tags: asymptotics, power-series, special-functions

The usual Eisenstein is defined as
$$
E_{2n}(\tau) = \sum_{(m, m') \in \mathbb{Z}^2-(0,0)} \frac{1}{(m + m' \tau)^{2n}} \ .
$$
It has a generalization to twisted Eisenstein series ($\phi := e^{2\pi i\lambda}$),
\begin{align}
 E_{n \ge 1}\left[\begin{matrix}
  \phi \\ \theta
 \end{matrix}\right] \equiv & \ - \frac{B_n(\lambda)}{n!} \\
 & \ + \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\sum_{r \ge 0} \frac{(r + \lambda)^{n - 1}\theta^{-1} q^{r + \lambda}}{1 - \theta^{-1}q^{r + \lambda}}
 + \frac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!}\sum_{r \ge 1} \frac{(r - \lambda)^{n - 1}\theta q^{r - \lambda}}{1 - \theta q^{r - \lambda}} \ .
\end{align}

I wonder if the **$n\to \infty$ asymptotic behavior/large $n$ expansion** of $E_{2n}(\tau)$ or $E_n [\phi, \theta](\tau)$ is known in the literature?

Comment: This uses $n$ for both the *weight* (often written $k$) and in the integer pair $(m, n)$. This is confusing.

Comment: @davidlowryduda you are right, let me edit it. Thanks!